# Command 'next build' not working when trying to make build of my nextJS app

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Trying to build a nextJS app I made. Keep getting this big error:

```
next build
- info Creating an optimized production build  
- info Compiled successfully
- info Linting and checking validity of types  
- info Collecting page data  
[    ] - info Generating static pages (0/4)TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at exports.useContext (/home/solomoncurly/code/test2/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:118)
    at Head (/home/solomoncurly/code/test2/.next/server/pages/_error.js:282:44)
    at Wc (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at $c (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at Zc (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:145)
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at exports.useContext (/home/solomoncurly/code/test2/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:118)
    at Head (/home/solomoncurly/code/test2/.next/server/pages/_error.js:282:44)
    at Wc (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at $c (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at Zc (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:145)

Error occurred prerendering page "/500". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at exports.useContext (/home/solomoncurly/code/test2/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:118)
    at Head (/home/solomoncurly/code/test2/.next/server/pages/_error.js:282:44)
    at Wc (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at $c (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at Zc (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:145)

Error occurred prerendering page "/404". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at exports.useContext (/home/solomoncurly/code/test2/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:118)
    at Head (/home/solomoncurly/code/test2/.next/server/pages/_error.js:282:44)
    at Wc (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at $c (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at Zc (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:145)
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at exports.useContext (/home/solomoncurly/code/test2/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:28:118)
    at usePathname (/home/solomoncurly/code/test2/.next/server/chunks/256.js:1494:34)
    at ErrorBoundary (/home/solomoncurly/code/test2/.next/server/chunks/256.js:814:50)
    at Je (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:121:272)
    at Z (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:128:91)
    at Je (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:122:9)
    at Je (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:127:11)
    at Z (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:128:91)
    at Ke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:131:155)
    at Me (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:130:289)

Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at exports.useContext (/home/solomoncurly/code/test2/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:28:118)
    at usePathname (/home/solomoncurly/code/test2/.next/server/chunks/256.js:1494:34)
    at ErrorBoundary (/home/solomoncurly/code/test2/.next/server/chunks/256.js:814:50)
    at Je (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:121:272)
    at Z (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:128:91)
    at Je (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:122:9)
    at Je (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:127:11)
    at Z (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:128:91)
    at Ke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:131:155)
    at Me (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.edge.production.min.js:130:289)
- info Generating static pages (4/4)

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
    /_error: /404
    /_error: /500
    /page: /
```

I tried to make a new nextJS app, and tried to build the boilerplate. Still getting same problem.
Am using new NextJs version, one that uses app router, not pages router.

Expected a final build version that I could host on render.

Answer (score 0):

npm start build gave more readable error mssgs.
Was missing a dependency, constants, apparently thats needed to build a next app